# Express Router - different routes with same suffixes

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 routes:

1. `/api/system/list` - list my systems
2. `/api/system/:systemId/books/list` - list books of current system

And different file for each API:

**systemAPI.js:**

```
const list = router.get('/list', Validate(Validation.list), listHandler)
return {
    routes: [list]
}
```

**bookAPI.js:**

```
const list = router.get('/list', Validate(Validation.list), listHandler)
return {
    routes: [list]
}
```

Finally, use the above routes:

```
express.use('/api/system', systemAPI.routes)
express.use('/api/system/:systemId/book', bookAPI.routes)
```

The problem is, when I'm entering list-books API (`/api/system/:systemId/books/list`), its actually calling the list-systems API (`/api/system/list`)

**Update: Solved!**

I had 2 main problems:

1. routes order (in `app.use(..)`)
2. use different instance of `Express.Router()` on each API

Refer the answer below for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing the order of the routes and this will probably solve your problem:

```
express.use('/api/system/:systemId/book', bookAPI.routes);
express.use('/api/system', systemAPI.routes);
```

The reason is that express evaluates routes 'greedily' and it will even resolve to partial matches. So, it is important to keep the more specific routes first before the more general ones.

Also, I think you are using the express router wrong according to the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) the systemAPI:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/list', Validate(Validation.list), listHandler)

module.exports = router;
```

The bookAPI route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/list', Validate(Validation.list), listHandler)

module.exports = router;
```

Finally import the routers and use them:

```
const express = require('express');
const bookRouter = require('./bookAPI'); //set the file paths based on your file structure
const systemRouter = require('./systemAPI');
const app = express();

app.use('/api/system/:systemId/book', bookRouter);
app.use('/api/system', systemRouter);
```

Comment: Same result, but if I'm changing the order of the API's constructions I'm getting another results. I think this is about to be solved

Comment: I have modified the answer. Try it now.

Comment: Should I use a new instance of express.Router() on each API? by now I'm using the same, this might be the problem?

Comment: Yes, you should use a different one for each route or rather group of routes. If you notice I instantiate a new router in each file.

Comment: Yes I did notice, and this is the main diff between our versions. actually its working now.